# Wix SetProperty if Property does not have a value

Tags: wix

I have the following code in my WiX installer:

```
<Property Id="CONFIGPATH" />
<SetProperty Id="CONFIGPATH" After="AppSearch" Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]servers.cfg">NOT CONFIGPATH</SetProperty>
```

The intention is that the user may pass a custom `CONFIGPATH` to the installer. If they do not pass a custom path, a default path targetting the installation folder is used. However, this code does not work. `SetProperty` never fires.

If instead I write:

```
<Property Id="CONFIGPATH" />
<SetProperty Id="CONFIGPATH" After="AppSearch" Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]servers.cfg"></SetProperty>
```

The property is updated to (the calculated value of) `[INSTALLFOLDER]servers.cfg` correctly.

Why might this be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, `AppSearch` is too early in the install sequence. It was necessary to change the code to a later point in the sequence:

```
<Property Id="CONFIGPATH" />
<SetProperty Id="CONFIGPATH" Sequence="execute" 
             Before="InstallFiles" 
             Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]servers.cfg">NOT CONFIGPATH</SetProperty>
```

Comment: The reason is explained in the note for RemoveFolderEx (http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/removefolderex.html). `MSI doesn't create properties for the Directory hierarchy in your package until later, in the CostFinalize action.` So if you try to set the property before CostFinalize (AppSearch is before this) INSTALLFOLDER doesn't actually have a value. Not totally sure why it updates to `[INSTALLFOLDER]servers.cfg` and not just `servers.cfg`

Comment: @BrianSutherland To clarify, when set to `After="AppSearch"` the property is updated to the calculated value of `[INSTALLFOLDER]servers.cfg`, so something like `c:/install/servers.cfg`. It's just that `SetProperty` does not fire when the `NOT CONFIGPATH` condition is present. This is surprising given when you have written. Perhaps even though the property is set before the directory hierarchy exists, the `[INSTALLFOLDER]` token is resolved to its value later on?